# Android: Recycler View, how do I block multiple onClick events

Tags: android

This is my handler for managing click events for when an item is selected on the recycler view. Nothing special.

```
        @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NavigationLeftDrawerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.setNavigationItemContent(titles[position], icons[position]);
        holder.getEntireItem().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(onLeftNavigationDrawerItemSelected != null){
                   onLeftNavigationDrawerItemSelected.onLeftNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);                                      
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

However the problem  i am having is if i put two fingers on the list i.e. one finger on item 1 and the other on item 3. Both events will be processed which is causing two activities to be started. How would i go about preventing the selection of another item whilst another is held down?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem for months, so I show my solution, but I think there must be a better solution.
I will also be waiting for someone suggests something better to implement it.

1. Make SingletonClass something like this:

   /**
    Created by Ceaggar on 7/17/15.
   */

   public class PreventListener {
   private static PreventListener instance;
   private boolean mIsClickEnable = true;
   private boolean mRunnableEnable = true;

   private PreventListener(){}

   private static synchronized PreventListener getInstance(){
       if(instance == null){
           instance = new PreventListener();
       }
       return instance;
   }

   public static boolean getClickEnable(){

   ```
   return getInstance().verifyEnable();
   ```

   }

   private boolean verifyEnable(){

   ```
   if (mIsClickEnable){
       mIsClickEnable = false;
       if (mRunnableEnable){
           mRunnableEnable = false;
           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {@Override public void run(){
               mRunnableEnable = true;
               mIsClickEnable = true;
               System.gc();
           }}, 500);
       }
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }}}
   ```
2. use it.

`@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NavigationLeftDrawerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.setNavigationItemContent(titles[position], icons[position]);
    holder.getEntireItem().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (PreventListener.getClickEnable()) {
                //intent
            }
        }
    });
}`

PD: I don't know to speak in english very well, so apologize for this.